# How Android normalizes estimated pressure on capacitive devices

Tags: android, touchscreen

I'm currently working on research in which we employ a task where participants tap a touch screen with the ball of their foot as many times as they can for a period of time. One of the variables the app measures is "pressure". The phones we are running the app on have capacitive touch screens. I am aware of how capacitive touch screens estimate pressure through measuring surface area.

Digging through documentation has led me [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#AXIS_PRESSURE). The phrase I am curious about is: "The value is *normalized* to..." Has there been anything stated on how this normalization takes place? Specifically, would it be normalized for each user over time given differences in finger size? Finally, could this normalization apply at least roughly to taps of the foot? In my own dataset, I see a fair number of instances of pressure values exceeding 1.

Comment: "Has there been anything stated on how this normalization takes place?" -- if you mean in terms of documentation, my guess is that this is not documented. At best, the source code would be the definitive source of information. I say "at best" because it is possible that this gets into device-specific approaches, customized by manufacturers. "would it be normalized for each user over time given differences in finger size?" -- that would surprise me, though I cannot rule it out.